# Kernel replaced boot.img is the same as stock one

Tags: android, kernel, samsung

I'm really struggling to make a custom kernel for the sm-a035f. The compiling is not a problem,but flashing the zimage is.Thanks( Im also new here so forgive me mistake)

I followed someone answer using Imgutil to replace the kernel in the stock boot.img with the zimage using

`imgutil /r /v boot.img kernel`

Of course i renamed zimage to kernel. Then I flashed the kernel but there was no change. Localversion and cpu governor unchanged.Someone suggested to edit the boot.img with hex editor but it very hard for newbies like me.

Comment: Please include the commands you use for flashing are at least describe what tool(s) you use and how you flash the kernel.